# Initializing varibles from array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to declare and assign default values to variables

```
let country, state, fruits;
let checkBoxfields = ['country', 'state', 'fruits'];
checkBoxfields.forEach(field=>{
    if(some condition){
        return field = true;
    }else{
        field = false;
    }
```

I want final output as such

```
country = true;
state = false;
fruits = true;
```

Comment: Can you add more information about what problem you are having implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the structure is consistent and value are always in the same order, then you can map and destructure value in variable with desired name something like this

```js
let checkBoxfields = ['country', 'state', 'fruits'];
let [country, state, fruits] = checkBoxfields.map(field => {
  return field === 'country' || field === 'fruits'
})

console.log(country, state, fruits)
```

---

If the variables are defined in global scope you can use window to reference variable, ***That being said you should avoid using global as much as possible it has it's own drawback, makes code so hard to debug***

```js
var country, state, fruits;
const checkBoxfields = ['country', 'state', 'fruits'];
checkBoxfields.forEach(field => {
  if (field === 'country' || field === 'fruits') {
    window[field] = true;
  } else {
    window[field] = false;
  }
});


console.log(country,state,fruits)
```

Comment: No! The structure may change, based on the condition

Comment: @RohitHannurkar the other answer is pretty much what you need in that condition

Comment: Thank you @CodeManiac for the Answer, I will be going with Abito answer, considering the variables are not declared in global scope as you rightly said it has its own drawback and hard to debug

Answer (score 3):

You can create an empty object and then iterate over the `checkBoxFields` and then populate the object as needed

```js
const obj = {};

const checkBoxfields = ['country', 'state', 'fruits'];
checkBoxfields.forEach(field => {
    if (some condition) {
        obj[field] = true;
    } else {
        obj[field] = false;
    }
});
```

Sample output

```
console.log(obj); // {country: false, state: true, fruits: true}
```

Comment: I don't want object, I want a direct variable with value

Comment: Are these variable declared in global scope ? @RohitHannurkar

Comment: Yes the declaration is in global scope

Comment: You can take out the variables by using `const {country, state, fruits} = obj`

Comment: Yes I will go with this answer, thwnk you  @Abito